# module.exports function undefined when passing in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my Node.js app, I'm passing in variables to functions by using `require` like so:

```
console.log(require('../controllers/controller')(variable)); // undefined
```

However, when I don't pass in the variable, it logs as a function, like so:

```
console.log(require('../controllers/controller')); // [Function]
```

My controllers are defined like this:

```
var Controller = function (variable) {
  this.variable = variable;
};

Controller.prototype.method = function (someInput, callback) {
  // can access this.variable;
};

module.exports = Controller;
```

I also get this error:

```
TypeError: Object function (variable) {
  this.variable = variable;
} has no method 'method'
```

Any idea as to where I'm going wrong here? I'm stuck at this step and not sure how to debug further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`require('../controllers/controller')` is a function. When you use it without `new` keyword it does not return anything. But when you use `new function()` it acts like a constuctor of the object. So what you want to do is to use `new` keyword if you need an object to be returned with its prototype methods.

```
var Controller = require('../controllers/controller'),
controller = new Controller(variable);
```

Comment: Wow, that was a dumb mistake. Editing your answer to show exactly what I should have done for others who make the same stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

this is an old thread, but I had this issue and the accepted answer didn't help me.

To create a module with a parameter, I use this code:

```
module.exports = function(pName) {
  return {
    test1: function() {
       console.log('In test 1 '+pName);
    },
    test2: function() {
       console.log('In test 2 '+pName);
    }
  };
};
```

And to call the module's functions:

```
var testModule = require('testModule')('David');
testModule.test1();
testModule.test2();
```